# How to Inline 2 Form Inputs

Tags: html, css, forms

I am having some trouble getting the two form inputs in a single horizonatal line.
You can see here:[Two Form Inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzbvz.png)

Here is my code:

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post">
   <div class="group" style="display: inline;">
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Username" style="width: 20%;"/>
   <textarea name="msg" id="msg" placeholder="Enter Message" style="width: 75%;"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="sbtbtn" value="Send Message"/>
   </form>
```

Please let me know how can i set them in a single horizontal line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post">
   <div class="group" style="display: flex;">
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Username" style="width: 20%;"/>
   <textarea name="msg" id="msg" placeholder="Enter Message" style="width: 75%;"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="sbtbtn" value="Send Message"/>
   </form>
```

Comment: Nothing changed, still same issue.

Comment: What nothing changed ? Username and message in single horizontal line.

Comment: No, its still as the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `display: flex` for the `.group`

Comment: Try adding !important since there may be some overriding properties

Comment: Tried, still the same as the image above.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post">
   <div class="group" style="display:flex !important;">
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Username" style="width: 20%;"/>
   <textarea name="msg" id="msg" placeholder="Enter Message" style="width: 75%;"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="sbtbtn" value="Send Message"/>
</form>
```

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post">
   <div class="group" style="display: inline;display:flex;">
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Username" style="width: 20%;"/>
   <textarea name="msg" id="msg" placeholder="Enter Message" style="width: 75%;"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="sbtbtn" value="Send Message"/>
   </form>
```

Comment: Nope, still same issue.

Comment: Which browser you are using ?

Comment: I am using Chrome.

Comment: okay, it seems like a problem with your "group" class. Try my edited answer. and tell me if it is helpful to you or not?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my input type from textarea to text and this did my job.

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post">
   <div class="group" style="display:flex;">
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Username" style="width: 20%;"/>
   <input type="text" name="msg" id="msg" placeholder="Enter Message" style="width: 80%;"/>
   </div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="sbtbtn" value="Send Message"/>
   </form>
```

Thanks for helping me out.